# Problems in verifying the definition of module

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm looking at a proof and I have some problems.

Let $G$ be a group and $A$ an abelian, normal subgroup of $G$. I consider $H=G/A$, the quotient group.

Why can I see $A$ as a $\mathbb ZH$-module by conjugation?

Moreover I have not understand what are the properties that I have to verify in order to prove that $\mathbb ZH$ is a module.

Many thanks!

Comment: You should write $\mathbb Z$ instead of $Z$, that's "\mathbb Z".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A $\mathbb{Z}H$-module is the same as an abelian group $A$ with a homomorphism $H \to \mathrm{Aut}(A)$. (This follows from the universal property of the group ring; no computations are needed even though many authors still do them.)

We have the homomorphism $G \to \mathrm{Aut}(G)$ which maps $g \in G$ to the conjugation map $(x \mapsto g x g^{-1})$. Since $A$ is normal, we obtain a homomorphism $G \to \mathrm{Aut}(A)$ defined by the same formula. Since $A$ is abelian, it is seen that $A$ lies in the kernel of $G \to \mathrm{Aut}(A)$. Hence, by the universal property of quotient groups ("fundamental theorem on homomorphisms"), we obtain a homomorphism of groups $G/A \to \mathrm{Aut}(A)$.

Thus, $A$ becomes a $\mathbb{Z}[G/A]$-module (without doing any computation). Explicitly, a coset $g \bmod A$ multiplies an element $a \in A$ to $g a g^{-1}$, and the action on a general element of $\mathbb{Z}[G/A]$ is given by $\mathbb{Z}$-linear extension.

Answer (score 1):

Since $A$ is normal in $G$, $G$ acts on $A$ by conjugation, i.e. for any $g \in G$ and any $a\in A$, we have $gag^{-1} \in A$ (we consider conjugation from the left here, conjugation from the right works completely analogous). Now, since $A$ is abelian, the action of $A$ on itself by conjugation from the left is trivial, i.e. for any $a,b \in A$, we have $aba{-1} = baa^{-1} = b$, that is $a$ acts as the identity. This means that the action of $G$ on $A$ by conjugation from the left factors through to an action of $G/A$ on $A$ by conjugation from the left. In other words: if we pick a coset $gA \in G/A$ and two elementes $ga, ga' \in gA$ with $a, a' \in A$, then the actions of $ga$ and $ga'$ on $A$ by conjugation from the left are identical (check that). So we have an action of $G/A = H$ on $A$ by conjugation from the left. This action is a "permutation representation" of $H$ on $A$, since conjugation permutes the elements of $A$
Now we can consider the group ring $\mathbb Z H$ and the $\mathbb Z$-module $\mathbb ZA$ (incidentally, $\mathbb ZA$ is also the group ring of $A$ over $\mathbb Z$). It is a general fact from representation theory that the permutation representation of $H$ on $A$ from above induces a $\mathbb Z$-linear representation of the Ring $\mathbb ZH$ on the $\mathbb Z$-module $\mathbb ZA$, just by "linear extension". More specifically, pick an element $$x := \zeta_1 g_1H+ \zeta_2 g_2H \in H$$ with $\zeta_1, \zeta_2 \in \mathbb Z$ and $g_1,g_2\in G$ (there could be more summands, but two are sufficient for demonstrational purposes). Further, pick an element $$v := \eta_1a_1 + \eta_2a_2 \in \mathbb ZA$$ with $\eta_1,\eta_2 \in \mathbb Z$ and $a_1,a_2 \in A$ (again, two summands are sufficient). Then the action of $x$ on $v$ is given by $x\cdot v = (\zeta_1 g_1H+ \zeta_2 g_2H)(\eta_1a_1 + \eta_2a_2) = \zeta_1\eta_1g_1a_1g_1^{-1} + \zeta_1\eta_2g_1a_2g_1^{-1} + \zeta_2\eta_1g_2a_1g_2^{-1} + \zeta_2\eta_2g_2a_2g_2^{-1}.$ You see, we extend the permutation representation of $H$ on $A$ from above linearly to $\mathbb Z$-linear combinations of elements of $H$ and $A$.
In that way, $\mathbb ZA$ is a $\mathbb ZH$-module.